# Can the map in Don't Starve contain an island?

Tags: dont-starve

After jumping through a wormhole, I seem to be on a section of the map that is an island.

I haven't been able to fully explore the entire map due to a series of Killer Bees' nests right where a land bridge would logically be located.

Do islands exist in Don't Starve?  I just want to know if it's worth taking on those Killer Bees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, Islands do exist**. Both in adventure mode (one level is actually only islands with wormhole connections) as in survival mode.

If you find a land bridge with killer bees, most likely there's land beyond. Might be worth exploring. Craft a bugnet or lead the bees to another victim to minimize damage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there is a land bridge there.  I haven't been able to get close enough to it!  Thanks for the answer!